# How to run ulimit in a script with other application

Tags: shell-script, gnome-terminal, ulimit

We have following script (in CentoS 6) in our lab to execute our applications with its output one-by-one.

```
cd A/
sleep 1
gnome-terminal -t A --tab -e "./app1"
cd ../B/
sleep 1
gnome-terminal -t b --tab -e "./app2" 
sleep 2
gnome-terminal -t c --tab -e "./app3"
```

This is working perfect.

Now what we want is to generate core dump files for one of our application (i.e. app3)
`ulimit -c` shows `0` by default, and I don't want to change its default value.

`gnome-terminal -t c --tab -e "ulimit -c unlimited ; ./c"` is not working, When googled found  that to run into a script it should be, `sh -c "ulimit -c unlimited"`.

`gnome-terminal -t c --tab -e "sh -c "ulimit -c unlimited"` is working perfect.
But,
`gnome-terminal -t c --tab -e "sh -c "ulimit -c unlimited ; ./app3"` is NOT working.

How can I enable core dump for app3 only? **NOTE: We don't want this globally.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways of doing this.

## Use a proper chain-loading command.

Instead of using the shell built-in command `ulimit`, use commands that were developed for this purpose, from [the various daemontools-family toolsets](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html):

- [`softlimit`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/softlimit.html) from daemontools
- `softlimit` from freedt
- [`softlimit`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/softlimit.8.html) from daemontools-encore
- [`softlimit`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/softlimit.html) from nosh
- [`s6-softlimit`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-softlimit.html) from s6
- [`chpst`](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html) from runit
- [`runlimit`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runlimit.8) from perp

So one would run, using `softlimit` from the nosh toolset as an example:

```
gnome-terminal -t A --tab -e "softlimit --coresize unlimited ./app1"
```

## Use a subshell within the script.

This applies the limit to the terminal emulator process as well.  In this case this will be fairly benign.  But if one is applying other limits such as open file handle limits or process forking limits this can be problematic.

```
(ulimit -c unlimited ; urxvt -e "./app1")
```

Note that *this will not work with GNOME Terminal or the client-server variant of Unicode RXVT*.  Both of those do not directly invoke the terminal emulator as a child of your script.  They perform a remote invocation via a server process, which will not have nor acquire the resource limits set in your script.

## Make GNOME Terminal run a shell that runs `ulimit`.

Remember that you have to build this from the bottom upwards.

1. You want the actual shell that does the work to run the command list

   ```
   ulimit -c unlimited ; exec "./app1"
   ```
2. To pass this command list to `sh` it needs to be *all one argument* after `-c`, so needs to be quoted:

   ```
   sh -c "ulimit -c unlimited ; exec \"./app1\""
   ```
3. To pass the `sh` invocation to GNOME Terminal, that too needs to be *all one argument* after `-e`, so a second level of quoting needs to be applied:

   ```
   gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "ulimit -c unlimited ; exec \"./app1\""'
   ```

Comment: All 3 arrows are right on Bulls Eye!!

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit -c` will not give you the hard limit, it will give you the soft limit. The hard limit can only be changed by the superuser and the softlimit can be changed by anyone. Changing the soft limit will only affect that process.

On MacOS:

```
$ charlie on macbook in ~
❯❯ ulimit -aS
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 7168
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

$ charlie on macbook in ~
❯❯ ulimit -aH
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) unlimited
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 65532
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1064
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

In your case, the hard limit is likely unlimited and the soft limit is 0 by default. You can change the soft limit in that process, eeither by using `ulimit` or by editing the `/proc/FD/limits` file directly.

Comment: This is NOT answer for my question, my question is **How can I enable core dump for app3 only?** by using script.

Comment: @Tejas that is an answer to your question, you can change the processes ulimit without changing the system hard ulimit as long as the system hard ulimit is not 0 (it likely isn't). So get the pid of app3 and change the ulimit.